# How do I make Selenium find_element_by_xpath inside tag formattable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I have a dataframe with ticker names and IDs, from [here](https://www.psx.com.pk/psx/resources-and-tools/listings/listed-companies) I have to first select the sector name and then the symbol both of which I'm nest looping through, then I'm brute forcing through the dataframe tickers to match with the resulting table that pops up.

```
for sec in sector.options[1:]:
    sec.click()
    for sym in symbol.options:
        table = sym.text
        for x in range(len(df)):
            if df['Ticker'][x] == table:
                #SEARCH ELEMENT BY TEXT AND THEN CLICK ON IT
                #text= find_element_by_css_selector('span:contains(df['Ticker'][x])')
                #text = find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), df['Ticker'][x]]').click()
```

My problem is after the if statement, I want to be able to search for the element text and then click on each of the matching tickers one by one and then copy the data from the table that pops up. I'm trying to use find_element_by_xpath but I dont know how to make the contains(text()) bit python formattable here? Any help would be appreciated

Code for running on your end:

```
chromedriver = "chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://www.psx.com.pk/psx/resources-and-tools/listings/listed-companies")
driver.maximize_window()

sector = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("sector"))
symbol = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("Symbol"))


for sec in sector.options[1:]:
    sec.click()
    for sym in symbol.options:
        table = sym.text
        for x in range(len(df)):
            if df['Ticker'][x] == table:
                #element1 = find_element_by_css_selector('span:contains("View All Companies")') #How to make this click on the text in the table
                #element1 = find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), df]')

driver.close
```

Comment: Where exactly do we have `View All Companies` in the web application?

Comment: AFAIU, you are iterating over sector and inside in nested loop you are iterating over symbol, Is that correct? If yes, then once you select the first sector and symbol what exactly you want to automate ?

Comment: Sorry the ```View All Companies``` name is irrelevant, it was a piece of code that I had copy pasted and was trying to modify. So basically: the goal is to click on each symbol on the website, that pops up a table with contact details, I want to copy all of that information and store it in a file. Right now it is partly complete as I have the symbol names all stored in a dataframe and am iterating over them one by one, I just need selenium to click on the symbol name to open up the table and then copy the information from the table that pops up.

Comment: so the table that pops up has this as a header `Company Address Book`? and you want to retrieve data from this table ?

Comment: Yes exactly that one, I want all the <tr> data with the tbody id addressbookdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target `addressbookdata` id since it's unique in HTML and then call the `get_attribute` to capture the `innerText`

**Code:**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
print(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "addressbookdata"))).get_attribute('innerText'))
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Yeah I can make that work. Goes beyond the scope of this thread but if you have some time could you help me in making the for loop logic work so that I can copy this information as per each sector->symbols for the entire site. If not is okay will eventually get to it through trial and error

Comment: Could you also create a new thread/ticket for the for loop issue that you've mentioned? As per the StackOverflow guidelines one thread should have one unique post.

Comment: Alright let me go through it myself first, if I can't figure it out will create a thread and share it with you. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: hi, if you can help I've got the rest of the functionality down. Just have trouble looping through sector/symbol dialogue boxes and passing them through as references. Please do help if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71893986/cant-get-selenium-to-loop-through-two-dialogue-box-options-correctly