# Can't get Selenium to loop through two dialogue box options correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

So basically: the goal is to click on each symbol for each sector on this [website](https://www.psx.com.pk/psx/resources-and-tools/listings/listed-companies), that pops up a table with contact details, I want to copy all of that information and store it in a file. Right now everything else has been tested and is working correctly. I just can't get Selenium to nested loop through sector and then all the symbols correctly.

I've tried this code with hard-coded parameters and it works perfectly, I now just need to pass on the values by reference for each sector/symbol so that I can loop through the entire site.

Can see the format of the website and the 2 dialogue box things [here](https://www.psx.com.pk/psx/resources-and-tools/listings/listed-companies). Am pasting the full workable code below but it's this bit thats causing me issues and doesnt loop through the site correctly:

```
sector = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("sector"))
symbol = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("Symbol"))

for sec in sector.options[1:]:
    sec.click()
    for sym in symbol.options[1:]:
        table = sym.text
```

It behaves very very erratically, I tried running through it stepwise with sleep commands but even I can't make sense of how it's operating right now, the rest of the operations are working fine I've tested them out by inputting manual tickers. I just need to select a sector, loop through all of the symbols in it, then select the next sector and all of it's symbols then and so on and so forth.

Code block for reproducing:

```
chromedriver = "chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://www.psx.com.pk/psx/resources-and-tools/listings/listed-companies")
driver.maximize_window()

sector = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("sector"))
symbol = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("Symbol"))


for sec in sector.options[1:]:
    sec.click()
    for sym in symbol.options[1:]:
        table = sym.text
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
        findelement = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, table)))
        findelement.click()
        
        # we do this after thingy has been clicked upon
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
        extract = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "addressbookdata")))

        #close the popup
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='close'][@data-dismiss='modal']"))).click()

        with open("output.txt", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(extract.get_attribute('innerText'))
    
    
driver.quit()
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Apologies, had been posting on this site for a few days so crossed my mind had to explain the problem again. Have made edits to the post.

Comment: _the goal is to click on each symbol_: I guess for the clickable symbols to surface you need to interact with two `Select` elements. correct? What are the steps to reproduce the issue? Where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: My code is availble in the post if you want to try to reproduce the issue, I am using 2 select statements to try to interact with the dialogue boxes. I'm stuck because I can't figure out the logic? In my end I'm looping through both of them correctly but that doesn't happen to be the case as evidenced by the output

Comment: @undetectedSelenium If you can look at the 1 answer posted/its discussion underneath do you think thats an IP blocking problem? Subsequent running of the program works fine so I dont think so? It just doesnt pick up some IDs well

Answer (score 0):

You have to have two-loop, especially nested ones.

One for Sector.

Second for Symbol.

Also, first symbol is default selected option which does not really have anything, so got to skip it.

PS: The application is a bit weird, for the first symbol, even manual address book does not show up.

**Code:**

```
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.psx.com.pk/psx/resources-and-tools/listings/listed-companies")

sector = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "sector"))))
symbol = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Symbol"))))

allSectorOptions = sector.options
for sector_ in allSectorOptions:
    if sector_.get_attribute('value') != "0":
        print("Inside sector loop")
        sector_.click();
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Selected sector:", sector_.text)
        allSymbolOptions = symbol.options
        for symbol_ in allSymbolOptions:
            if symbol_.get_attribute('value') != "0":
                print("Inside symbol loop")
                attempts = 0
                while attempts < 3:
                    try:
                        symbol_.click()
                        break
                    except StaleElementReferenceException as stale:
                        print(stale.msg)
                    attempts = attempts + 1
                print("Selected symbol:", symbol_.text)
                try:
                    address_data = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "addressbookdata")))
                    print(address_data.get_attribute('innerText'))
                    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='close'][@data-dismiss='modal']"))).click()
                except:
                    print("addressbookdata could not found for", symbol_.text)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output:**

```
Inside sector loop
Selected sector: Automobile assembler
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: AGTL
addressbookdata could not found for AGTL
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: ATLH
Company Address Book
Atlas Honda Limited

Representative  Mr. Saquib H. Shirazi
Designation Chief Executive
Company Atlas Honda Limited
Address 1-Mcleod Road , ,Lahore
Phone   042-37225015-17, 37233515-17
Phone 2 
Fax 042-37233518-37351119
Date of Listing 1965-10-15
Email   marrium.ahmed@atlashonda.com.pk
URL www.atlashonda.com.pk
Registrar   Hameed Majeed Associates (Pvt.) Ltd
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: DFML
Company Address Book
Atlas Honda Limited

Representative  Mr. Saquib H. Shirazi
Designation Chief Executive
Company Atlas Honda Limited
Address 1-Mcleod Road , ,Lahore
Phone   042-37225015-17, 37233515-17
Phone 2 
Fax 042-37233518-37351119
Date of Listing 1965-10-15
Email   marrium.ahmed@atlashonda.com.pk
URL www.atlashonda.com.pk
Registrar   Hameed Majeed Associates (Pvt.) Ltd
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: GHNI
Company Address Book
Atlas Honda Limited

Representative  Mr. Saquib H. Shirazi
Designation Chief Executive
Company Atlas Honda Limited
Address 1-Mcleod Road , ,Lahore
Phone   042-37225015-17, 37233515-17
Phone 2 
Fax 042-37233518-37351119
Date of Listing 1965-10-15
Email   marrium.ahmed@atlashonda.com.pk
URL www.atlashonda.com.pk
Registrar   Hameed Majeed Associates (Pvt.) Ltd
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: GHNL
Company Address Book
Dewan Farooque Motors Limited

Representative  Mr. Waseem-ul-Haque Ansari
Designation Chief Executive Officer
Company Dewan Farooque Motors Limited
Address Dewan Centre, 3-A, Lalazar , Beach Hotel Road,Karachi
Phone   111-364-111
Phone 2 
Fax 021-35630860
Date of Listing 2000-07-31
Email   info@dewan-motors.com
URL www.yousufdewan.com
Registrar   BMF Consultants Pakistan (Pvt.) Ltd.
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: HCAR
Company Address Book
Dewan Farooque Motors Limited

Representative  Mr. Waseem-ul-Haque Ansari
Designation Chief Executive Officer
Company Dewan Farooque Motors Limited
Address Dewan Centre, 3-A, Lalazar , Beach Hotel Road,Karachi
Phone   111-364-111
Phone 2 
Fax 021-35630860
Date of Listing 2000-07-31
Email   info@dewan-motors.com
URL www.yousufdewan.com
Registrar   BMF Consultants Pakistan (Pvt.) Ltd.
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: HINO
Company Address Book
Ghandhara Industries Limited

Representative  Mr. Ahmed Kuli Khan Khattak
Designation Chief Executive Officer
Company Ghandhara Industries Limited
Address F-3, Hub Chauki Road , S.I.T.E. Post Box No. 2706,Karachi
Phone   021-38709000
Phone 2 021-32560083-86
Fax 021-32560090-32564458
Date of Listing 1963-09-03
Email   info@gil.com.pk
URL www.gil.com.pk
Registrar   CDC Share Registrar Services Limited
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: INDU
Company Address Book
Hinopak Motors Limited

Representative  Mr. Takayuki Kizawa
Designation President & Chief Executive Officer
Company Hinopak Motors Limited
Address D-2, S.I.T.E , Manghopir Road,Karachi
Phone   021-32563510-18, 111-252-525
Phone 2 
Fax 021-32563028
Date of Listing 1988-05-25
Email   info@hinopak.com
URL www.hinopak.com
Registrar   FAMCO Associates (Pvt) Limited
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: MTL
Company Address Book
Indus Motor Company Limited

Representative  Mr. Ali Asghar Abbas Jamali
Designation Chief Executive Officer
Company Indus Motor Company Limited
Address Plot No.NWZ/1/P-1 , Port Qasim Authority, Bin Qasim,Karachi
Phone   021-34720041-48-34721100
Phone 2 021-111-869-682
Fax 021-34720056-34720054
Date of Listing 1992-06-29
Email   anam.khan@toyota-indus.com
URL www.toyota-indus.com
Registrar   CDC Share Registrar Services Limited
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: PSMC
Company Address Book
Millat Tractors Limited

Representative  Syed Muhammad Irfan Aqueel
Designation Chief Executive
Company Millat Tractors Limited
Address Sheikhupura Road , Distt: Shahdara,Lahore
Phone   042-111-200-786, 37911021-25
Phone 2 
Fax 042-37925835-37924166
Date of Listing 1965-02-02
Email   info@millat.com.pk
URL www.millat.com.pk
Registrar   Hameed Majeed Associates (Pvt.) Ltd
addressbookdata could not found for PSMC
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: SAZEW
Company Address Book
Pak Suzuki Motor Company Limited

Representative  Mr. Masafumi Harano
Designation Chief Executive Officer
Company Pak Suzuki Motor Company Limited
Address DSU-13, Pakistan Steel Industrial Estates , Bin Qasim,Karachi
Phone   021-34723552-58
Phone 2 021-34723532 (Direct)
Fax 021-34723521-23
Date of Listing 1985-09-10
Email   contact@paksuzuki.com.pk
URL www.paksuzuki.com.pk
Registrar   CDC Share Registrar Services Limited
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: SAZEWR
Company Address Book
Pak Suzuki Motor Company Limited

Representative  Mr. Masafumi Harano
Designation Chief Executive Officer
Company Pak Suzuki Motor Company Limited
Address DSU-13, Pakistan Steel Industrial Estates , Bin Qasim,Karachi
Phone   021-34723552-58
Phone 2 021-34723532 (Direct)
Fax 021-34723521-23
Date of Listing 1985-09-10
Email   contact@paksuzuki.com.pk
URL www.paksuzuki.com.pk
Registrar   CDC Share Registrar Services Limited
Inside sector loop
Selected sector: Automobile parts & accessories
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: AGIL
addressbookdata could not found for AGIL
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: ATBA
addressbookdata could not found for ATBA
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: BELA
Company Address Book
Bela Automotives Limited

Representative  Mr. Abdul Mateen Allahwala
Designation Chief Executive
Company Bela Automotives Limited
Address Plot No.1 & 3 Mouza Pathra , Hub Chowki,Baluchistan
Phone   
Phone 2 Mob.0300-8271368
Fax 
Date of Listing 1994-09-27
Email   belaautomotive@gmail.com
URL 
Registrar   M/s. JWAFFS Registrar Services (Pvt.) Limited
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: BWHL
Company Address Book
Bela Automotives Limited

Representative  Mr. Abdul Mateen Allahwala
Designation Chief Executive
Company Bela Automotives Limited
Address Plot No.1 & 3 Mouza Pathra , Hub Chowki,Baluchistan
Phone   
Phone 2 Mob.0300-8271368
Fax 
Date of Listing 1994-09-27
Email   belaautomotive@gmail.com
URL 
Registrar   M/s. JWAFFS Registrar Services (Pvt.) Limited
addressbookdata could not found for BWHL
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: DWAE
Company Address Book
Baluchistan Wheels Limited

Representative  Mr. Razzak H.M. Bengali
Designation Chief Executive
Company Baluchistan Wheels Limited
Address 1st Floor, State Life Building No.3 , Dr. Ziauddin Ahmed Road,Karachi
Phone   021-35689259-35687502
Phone 2 
Fax 021-35684003
Date of Listing 1994-01-18
Email   bwlho@cyber.net.pk
URL www.bwheels.com
Registrar   THK Associates (Private) Limited
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: EXIDE
Company Address Book
Baluchistan Wheels Limited

Representative  Mr. Razzak H.M. Bengali
Designation Chief Executive
Company Baluchistan Wheels Limited
Address 1st Floor, State Life Building No.3 , Dr. Ziauddin Ahmed Road,Karachi
Phone   021-35689259-35687502
Phone 2 
Fax 021-35684003
Date of Listing 1994-01-18
Email   bwlho@cyber.net.pk
URL www.bwheels.com
Registrar   THK Associates (Private) Limited
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: GTYR
Company Address Book
Baluchistan Wheels Limited

Representative  Mr. Razzak H.M. Bengali
Designation Chief Executive
Company Baluchistan Wheels Limited
Address 1st Floor, State Life Building No.3 , Dr. Ziauddin Ahmed Road,Karachi
Phone   021-35689259-35687502
Phone 2 
Fax 021-35684003
Date of Listing 1994-01-18
Email   bwlho@cyber.net.pk
URL www.bwheels.com
Registrar   THK Associates (Private) Limited
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: LOADS
Company Address Book
Dewan Automotive Engineering Limited

Representative  Mr. Waseem-ul-Haque Ansari
Designation Chief Executive Officer
Company Dewan Automotive Engineering Limited
Address Dewan Centre, 3-A, Lalazar , Beach Hotel Road,Karachi
Phone   111-364-111
Phone 2 
Fax 021-35630860
Date of Listing 1986-09-02
Email   info@yousufdewan.com
URL www.yousufdewan.com
Registrar   BMF Consultants Pakistan (Pvt.) Ltd.
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: PTL
Company Address Book
Ghandhara Tyre and Rubber Company Limited (Formerly: General Tyre)

Representative  Mr. Hussain Kuli Khan Khattak
Designation Chief Executive Officer
Company Ghandhara Tyre and Rubber Company Limited (Formerly: General Tyre)
Address H-23/2, Landhi Industrial Trading Estate , Landhi,Karachi
Phone   021-111-487-487
Phone 2 021-35080172-81
Fax 021-35080171
Date of Listing 1982-06-21
Email   farhan.ahmad@gentipak.com
URL www.generaltyre.com.pk
Registrar   CDC Share Registrar Services Limited
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: THALL
Company Address Book
Ghandhara Tyre and Rubber Company Limited (Formerly: General Tyre)

Representative  Mr. Hussain Kuli Khan Khattak
Designation Chief Executive Officer
Company Ghandhara Tyre and Rubber Company Limited (Formerly: General Tyre)
Address H-23/2, Landhi Industrial Trading Estate , Landhi,Karachi
Phone   021-111-487-487
Phone 2 021-35080172-81
Fax 021-35080171
Date of Listing 1982-06-21
Email   farhan.ahmad@gentipak.com
URL www.generaltyre.com.pk
Registrar   CDC Share Registrar Services Limited
addressbookdata could not found for THALL
Inside sector loop
Selected sector: Bonds
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: AGSILSC
addressbookdata could not found for AGSILSC
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: AKBLTFC6
addressbookdata could not found for AKBLTFC6
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: AKBLTFC7
addressbookdata could not found for AKBLTFC7
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: AZLCLTFC2
addressbookdata could not found for AZLCLTFC2
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: BAFLTFC6
addressbookdata could not found for BAFLTFC6
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: BAFLTFC7
addressbookdata could not found for BAFLTFC7
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: BIPLSC
addressbookdata could not found for BIPLSC
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: CNERGYSC
addressbookdata could not found for CNERGYSC
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: EPCLSC
addressbookdata could not found for EPCLSC
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: HBLTFC2
addressbookdata could not found for HBLTFC2
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: HUBCSC2
addressbookdata could not found for HUBCSC2
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: HUBCSC4
addressbookdata could not found for HUBCSC4
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: HUBPHLSC
addressbookdata could not found for HUBPHLSC
Inside symbol loop
Selected symbol: JSBLTFC1
```

Comment: Output is bit lengthy, so cannot paste here.

Comment: I think your code is missing a lot of companies but I'm not sure why? For example the code gives the output 

Selected symbol: WAVES
addressbookdata could not found for WAVES

however I went to check manually and WAVES data does exist in the database. Might have to change approach a bit, am thinking of brute forcing through it a bit

Comment: Seems like they are detecting my ip and not letting me get the desired output.

Comment: also, the code may be looking like it's complex, however, it's just a representation of what we do manually to get all the details.

Comment: These Pakistani websites aren't advanced enough to have protection against scrappers and stuff. I'll try changing my approach around a bit, just need to crack the opening for loops bit I've got the rest of the logic down

Comment: They are quite advance though, I had to connect to VPN to just open them manually :)

Comment: Oh. Is a .pk site with all Pakistani stock data and stuff on it so might just have a basic geolock on it. Anyways thanks a lot for the help! Will update you tomorrow if I figure it out, I think I do have a basic idea on how to finish this finally but lets see if I'm able to make it materialize

Comment: IT'S DONE. Have scrapped all companies successfully, used same approach just tweaked the opening parameters a bit (still took me the whole day). But is finally over.